# How can I install the R kernel on an AWS SageMaker notebook instance without internet access?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, conda, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to install the R kernel on an AWS SageMaker notebook instance that has no internet access. AWS provides documentation on how to install the R kernel on a notebook instance with internet access [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/install_r_kernel/install_r_kernel.ipynb). However, I am trying to install the R kernel on a notebook instance without internet access. Their [documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/install_r_kernel/install_r_kernel.ipynb) states that r-essentials must be installed. I've tried downloading/installing the r-essentials tar.bz2 archive from the [Anaconda package repository](https://anaconda.org/r/r-essentials/files). However, it seems like the r-essentials is simply a metapackage and does not contain the actual packages that are to be installed.

Installing r-essentials using the tar.bz2 archive:
[image: install r-essentials via tar.bz2 archive]

Checking if the R kernel exists in the notebook dropdown:
[image: Notebook drop down]

Is there a workaround for this? The goal is to get the R kernel on the notebook instance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the r-essential tar file is just meta data of list of R packages that need to be installed. Have you tried building the R package manually[1]?
Another possible solution is going through the list of R packages, upload the tar file and install the ones you need.

[1]https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Installing-R-under-Unix_002dalikes